# Como ordenar JSON de API em ordem alfabética decrescente

Tags: javascript, react

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação onde em uma das páginas é mostrada uma lista de modelos de veículos resultados de uma requisição feita a uma API. Fiz o código de requisição e listagem dessa forma:

```
 const [modelos, setModelos] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`https://parallelum.com.br/fipe/api/v1/${window.location.pathname.split('/')[1]}/marcas/${id()}/modelos`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => setModelos(data))
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
}, [])

return(
    <>
    <div className="container">
        <ul>
            {(modelos.modelos?.map(modelo => (              
                <li key={modelo.codigo}>
                    <p>{modelo.codigo} - {modelo.nome}</p>
                </li>
            )))}
        </ul>
    </div>
    <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={() => window.history.back()}>Voltar</button>
    </>
)
```

Percebam que tive que usar um "modelos?.map" pra que a listagem funcionasse pois estava recebendo o erro modelos.map is not a function.

Minha dúvida é: como faço pra ordenar o resultado da requisição em ordem alfabética decrescente? Já tentei utilizar o seguinte código sem sucesso:

```
    modelos.modelos?.sort(function(a, b) {
  if(a.nome > b.nome) {
    return -1;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Então, o que você quer fazer eh algo complexo, a forma que voce havia tentado realmente funciona, porem com uma forma de retorno diferente.

o @Franklin Dias colocou uma opção válida de utilização.

Quanto ao seu map com a interrogação, recomendo que trate melhor o seu array de itens, coloque ele no state e utilize um useMemo para fazer um parse, pois fica mais fácil de dar manutenção depois, e utilize o retorno do useMemo na renderização.

```
const parsedModelos = useMemo(() => {
   if (modelos.modelos) {
      // se precisasse alterar alguma coisa no array, vc alteraria aqui
      return modelos.modelos
   }

   return []
}, [modelos])
```

Então voce nao precisaria da interrogação

```
...
<ul>
   {parsedModelos.map(modelo => (              
      <li key={modelo.codigo}>
         <p>{modelo.codigo} - {modelo.nome}</p>
      </li>
    ))}
</ul>
...
```

Esta parte é apenas uma sugestão, seu code também vai funcionar do jeito que está

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).